# Tagging files with colors in OS X Finder from shell scripts

Tags: macos, applescript, finder

One can tag files and folders with a color in the Mac OS X Finder.
Is there a way to do this from a shell script?

Comment: See also https://superuser.com/questions/168927/mac-os-x-how-to-change-the-color-label-of-files-from-the-terminal

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This shell script takes the file or folder name as its first argument and the label index (0 for no label, 1 for red, ..., 7 for gray) as its second argument.

```
#!/bin/sh
osascript -e "tell application \"Finder\" to set label index of alias POSIX file \"`cd -P -- "$(dirname -- "$1")" && printf '%s\n' "$(pwd -P)/$(basename -- "$1")"`\" to $2"
```

More directly, if $filename is a shell variable with the absolute path name of the file or folder to be labeled and $label is a shell variable with the label index number,

```
osascript -e "tell application \"Finder\" to set label index of alias POSIX file \"$filename\" to $label"
```

is a shell command to assign the label to the file or folder.

Comment: This will fail if the filename contains double quotes or ends with a backslash.

Comment: @Kevin: Any solution to that?

Comment: @Kevin: Also... why would you have a filename containing double quotes? I thought that was invalid... or maybe just in Windows...

Comment: The only characters not allowed in filenames are NUL (U+0000) and the path separator (which is either "/" or ":" depending on which API you look through). A safe way to pass strings to AppleScript is to to give command-line args to `osascript` (that is, `osascript -e <script> <arg>` and then retrieve them using an `on run theArguments ... end run` handler inside the script.

Comment: The labels aren't in the same order as in Finder. 1 would be orange.

Answer (score 8):

Here's a quick python script I wrote:

https://github.com/danthedeckie/finder_colors

which sets the colours of folders and files from the commandline.

Usage:

```
finder_colors.py red /Users/daniel/src
```

sets the /Users/daniel/src directory to be red.

```
finder_colors.py /Users/daniel/src
```

returns the colour (in this case now, 'red').  If you're writing a python script, you can import finder_colors as a module, and use it directly (finder_colors.get(...), and finder_colors.set(...).

Comment: Would help more if you explain how you do it e.g. via relevant code examples of your solution.

Comment: Thanks @Pfitz - I've added usage information.  The way it works internally is using a built in python library to edit the extended attributes of the file.

I couldn't find an elegant native shell-scripting way to do this, and don't like the apple-script solutions.

Comment: Execuse me but your code is not working when scanning files like "/Desktop/image.jpeg". Do you have any ideas to fix that? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

Based on the responses here and in referenced posts, I made the following function and added it to my `~/.bash_profile` file:

```
# Set Finder label color
label(){
  if [ $# -lt 2 ]; then
    echo "USAGE: label [0-7] file1 [file2] ..."
    echo "Sets the Finder label (color) for files"
    echo "Default colors:"
    echo " 0  No color"
    echo " 1  Orange"
    echo " 2  Red"
    echo " 3  Yellow"
    echo " 4  Blue"
    echo " 5  Purple"
    echo " 6  Green"
    echo " 7  Gray"
  else
    osascript - "$@" << EOF
    on run argv
        set labelIndex to (item 1 of argv as number)
        repeat with i from 2 to (count of argv)
          tell application "Finder"
              set theFile to POSIX file (item i of argv) as alias
              set label index of theFile to labelIndex
          end tell
        end repeat
    end run
EOF
  fi
}
```

Answer (score 2):

One ugly way to do this would be:

```
exec osascript <<\EOF
tell app "Finder"

    -- [...]
    -- selecting the file
    -- [...]

    -- 4 is Blue
    set label index of thisItem to 4
end tell
```

Basically launching an applescript that uses finder to set the color.

I got the hints from:

(Color) http://www.macosxhints.com/article.php?story=20070602122413306

(Shell) http://www.macosxhints.com/article.php?story=20040617170055379

Answer (score 1):

There's also the command line tool 'setlabel' in the [osxutils](http://osxutils.sf.net) package.  It doesn't require AppleScript or that the Finder be running.

Answer (score 1):

This would use the same order for the colors as Finder.

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ $# -le 1 || ! "$1" =~ ^[0-7]$ ]]; then
  echo "Usage: label 01234567 file ..." 1>&2
  exit 1
fi

colors=( 0 2 1 3 6 4 5 7 )
n=${colors[$1]}
shift

osascript - "$@" <<END > /dev/null 2>&1
on run arguments
tell application "Finder"
repeat with f in arguments
set f to (posix file (contents of f) as alias)
set label index of f to $n
end repeat
end tell
end
END
```

I'm redirecting STDERR, because I got warnings like `2012-09-06 13:50:00.965 osascript[45254:707] CFURLGetFSRef was passed this URL which has no scheme (the URL may not work with other CFURL routines): test.txt` on 10.8. STDOUT is redirected because osascript prints the value of the last expression.