# Sending AppleEvents to Finder via Python

Tags: python, macos-carbon, finder, appleevents

I'm trying to send a kAESync AppleEvent to Python, but I can't seem to figure out how to do this. The documentation on the Carbon module seems sparse. There is a way to do this in Carbon, but I am not sure how it translates to Python using the Carbon module. How do I send the kAESync event for a file alias in Python?

The Carbon way to do this is outlined in this link:
http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/286995-finder-refresh-issue-in-mac-os-10-5.html

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Have you had a look at PyObjC?

Comment: @carrot-top: edited the question for clarity. yes, but afaik pyobjc discourages using NSAppleEventManager. I'm currently looking at appscript, but I am not sure what the kAESync event directly translates to.

Comment: The method in this [Perl question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3799826/how-can-i-edit-file-metadata-in-os-x/3800396#3800396) might work. Just call OSAScript from the command line.