# Mac OS X Finder Labels in Java

Tags: java, macos, file, label, finder

I have a directory which more directories. They are sorted by "Labels".

I want to use them in my Java programm too. But how to get the Label of a file?

Is there any library? Or do I have to write smth via JNA/JNI? Or maybe a Applescript-Bridge?

In short form: How do I get the Label of a File in Mac OS X?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why is this being downvoted? Seems like a legit question: `Can I use Java to make a native system call to get the Label of a file on a HFS File System?`

Answer (score 2):

Use the xattr command-line tool to get the metadata for the file(s) in question.

If the file has a label, there will be an attribute which looks like this:

com.apple.metadata:kMDLabel_qygkxhrfarhtxanqhi264amkku

You can then correlate the label string with the label color.

**Edit**
I believe osascript might provide an easier interface to getting/setting the extended metadata on files.

See [Tagging files with colors in OS X Finder from shell scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2435580/tagging-files-with-colors-in-os-x-finder-from-shell-scripts)

Comment: Is that the only Way? Also it does not shows up any metadata if the "file" is a directory. There appears then "com.apple.FinderInfo".

Answer (score 0):

For `10.6` and above ,you can use [NSURL](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html) instance method.

```
- (BOOL)getResourceValue:(id *)value forKey:(NSString *)key error:(NSError **)error
```

and

`- (BOOL)setResourceValue:(id)value forKey:(NSString *)key error:(NSError **)error`

with `NSURLLabelNumberKey` or `NSURLLabelColorKey`.

For `10.5`, use apple script.

Comment: This sounds nice but could you give me a more extended code example? :)

Comment: That answers how to do it in Objective C, but not Java.