# Read file tags in Java

Tags: java, macos

I have been trying to find a way to read file tags with Java, however, I have hit a roadblock.
I was hoping I can do something like this:

```java
String[] tags = file.getTags();
```

Or

```java
String[] tags = file.getAttributes().tags();
```

The use of a third-party library would also be good.

I was searching stuff up and found: [Tagging files with colors in OS X Finder from shell scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2435580/tagging-files-with-colors-in-os-x-finder-from-shell-scripts) and [Mac OS X Finder Labels in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9607132/mac-os-x-finder-labels-in-java). However, both used a shell script.

Comment: I'm not on a mac so I can't test, but try `Files.readAttributes(path)`. Also, it's very possible that there's just no API for this in the Java core libraries.

Comment: Try `System.out.println(Files.readAttributes(pathObject, "user:*"));`